# SQLite3 with Electron 13

Tags: node.js, sqlite, electron

Currently trying to use `sqlite3` with `electron` 13.1 and Node 14.17.3.

Running `electron-forge start` results in:

```
/home/victor/workplace/project/node_modules/node-addon-api/napi-inl.h: In member function ‘bool Napi::Object::Freeze()’:
/home/victor/workplace/project/node_modules/node-addon-api/napi-inl.h:1393:24: error: ‘napi_object_freeze’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘napi_object_expected’?
 1393 |   napi_status status = napi_object_freeze(_env, _value);
      |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                        napi_object_expected
/home/victor/workplace/project/node_modules/node-addon-api/napi-inl.h: In member function ‘bool Napi::Object::Seal()’:
/home/victor/workplace/project/node_modules/node-addon-api/napi-inl.h:1399:24: error: ‘napi_object_seal’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘napi_object’?
 1399 |   napi_status status = napi_object_seal(_env, _value);
      |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                        napi_object
⠴ Building module: sqlite3, Completed: 0../src/b
```

Looking at the readme of SQLite [here](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3#supported-platforms), it seems like support for Electron 13.1 is not available.

Is there any known workaround (that I could not find) or even another (compatible) package?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by overriding the sqlite node-addon-api dependency.
If you are using yarn, you can add the following lines to the package.json file:

```
"resolutions": {
"sqlite3/node-addon-api": "3.1.0" }
```